# Printing array to variable cell range VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a variable array which I want to print into another workbook range. As I loop through separate arrays and secondary workbooks, the cell I want to print to will change.

Some sheets will need to array to be printed to A6:N, some will need the array printed to A300:N etc. I want to get to the bottom of the list of existing data and 'paste' the array below it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
bottomrow2 = Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row
Set PasteCell = ClientBook.Sheets("PasteSheet").Range(Cells(bottomrow2 + 1,1),Cells(bottomrow2 + 1, 14))
Range(PasteCell & UBound(array)) = array
```

`PasteCell` is effectively trying to be my A1:N. It's worth noting that if I hard-code where to `paste` the array to, it works fine.

```
Range("A1:N" & UBound(array)) = array
'^This works fine.
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: You need to resize Paste Cell, so `Set PasteCell=PasteCell.Resize(ubound(array),14)` something like that.  Or just use the anchor cell maybe, set paste cell to just be bottomrow2,1 ?

Comment: Thanks, this worked. For some reason 'PasteCell' was appearing as a variant/range in my Watch Window. I brought it's declaration into the sub() and along with your help it's worked. Thanks again.

Comment: how did you declare `PasteCell` ?

Comment: I originally declared it as Range, at the top, before the array was constructed. Quite confused as to why it would appear as Variant/Range as the `Set PasteCell = ClientBook.Sheets("Media Traded").Range(Cells(bottomrow2 + 1, 1), Cells(bottomrow2 + 1, 14))` call was the first time it's called in multiple subs

Comment: Is it a range still before populated? In the top of the sub or the top of the module?

Comment: What's weirder is that I can't now recreate it. Perhaps some rogue lines of code at the bottom of the sub were confusing it. Thanks again for all of your help

Comment: no worries.  I've added as an answer too, to help others.  Mark as solution if you can.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to resize Paste Cell, so

`Set PasteCell=PasteCell.Resize(ubound(array),14)`

something like that. Or just use the anchor cell maybe, set paste cell to just be bottomrow2,1 ?